# 4 top quark production Feynman diagrams

Tags: particle-physics, quantum-chromodynamics

In [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1906.02805) in figure 1 they show the lowest order Feynman diagrams for four top production. Isn't it possible to have a single 4-gluon vertex (getting rid of the gluon propagator in the second diagram)? If so, isn't it also of the same order in $g$/$\alpha_s$?

Edit: upon going through it again after posting, it says "representative diagrams", meaning that the list is not exhaustive?